# GoogleMap is moved when another view is hidden, Xamarin

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/root"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/rel_layout_location"
      android:layout_gravity="right"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"
      android:background="@drawable/white_circular_shadow"
      android:layout_width="60dp"
      android:layout_height="60dp">
      <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/location"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/info_window_container"
      android:background="@color/white"
      android:visibility="gone"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
      <TextView
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/textview_title"
        android:text="How you doing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have access to the relativelayout:

```
relativelayout_info_container = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.info_window_container);
```

Everything is working fine, however when I try to hide the relative layout the map goes crazy (this is inside the MarkerClick):

```
googleMap.MarkerClick += MarkerClick;
```

then inside MarkerClick:

```
 relativelayout_info_container.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
```

It cancels the animation, it cancel the tapped marker function, it moves the map to the first location and zoom it was displayed like it has been reset.

Any ideas? If you need more information please let me know in the comments

UPDATE:

I just added another call to set padding to the map so it does not obscure the googlemap sign and the same problem occurs:

```
googleMap.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, <some_value>);
```

the change of the map padding is affecting changes I do to marker icons and camera updates inside MarkerClick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely irrelevant question. The problem really was in another part of my code. I had a ViewTreeObserver that was animating the map. Once I unsubscribed to it, everything just worked ;)